# cython compiling error: multiple definition of functions

Tags: python, compiler-errors, cython

I create a c file named test.c with two functions defined as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void hello_1(void){
    printf("hello 1\n");
}
void hello_2(void){
    printf("hello 2\n");
}
```

After that, I create test.pyx as follows:

```
import cython
cdef extern void hello_1()
```

The setup file is as follows:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

setup(cmdclass={'buld_ext':build_ext}, 
      ext_modules=[Extension("test",["test.pyx", "test.c"], 
                   include_dirs=[np.get_include()],
                   extra_compile_args=['-g', '-fopenmp'],
                   extra_link_args=['-g', '-fopenmp', '-pthread'])
    ])
```

When I run setup file, it always reports hello_1 and hello_2 have multiple definitions. Can anybody tell me the problem?

Comment: If this is your actual code, there are at least two problems: (1) you've misspelled `Extension`, `build_ext`, and possibly other things as well, and (2) you've got a file named `test.c` that's going to be overwritten by the file generated from `test.pyx`.

Comment: The file I posted before is not exactly the same as what I have, and I also made some typos.  I have corrected my question. The only problem I have here is because the c file name is the same as the automatically generated c file by cython. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a number of things wrong with your files as posted, and I have no idea which one is causing the problem in your real code—especially since the code you showed us doesn't, and can't possibly, generate those errors.

But if I fix all of the obvious problems, everything works. So, let's go through all of them:

Your `setup.py` is missing the imports at the top, so it's going to fail with a `NameError` immediately.

Next, there are multiple typos—`Extenson` for `Extension`, `buld_ext` for `build_ext`, and I think one more that I fixed but don't remember.

I stripped out the numpy and openmp stuff because it's not relevant to your problem, and it was easier to just get it out of the way.

When you fix all of that and actually run the setup, the next problem becomes immediately obvious:

```
$ python setup.py build_ext -i
running build_ext
cythoning test.pyx to test.c
```

You're either overwriting your `test.c` file with the file that gets built from `test.pyx`, or, if you get lucky, ignoring the generated `test.c` file and using the existing `test.c` as if it were the cython-compiled output of `test.pyx`. Either way, you're compiling the same file twice and trying to link the results together, hence your multiple definitions.

You can either configure Cython to use a non-default name for that file or, more simply, follow the usual naming conventions and don't have a `test.pyx` that tries to use a `test.c` in the first place.

So:

---

ctest.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void hello_1(void){
    printf("hello 1\n");
}
void hello_2(void){
    printf("hello 2\n");
}
```

test.pyx:

```
import cython
cdef extern void hello_1()
```

setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

setup(cmdclass={'build_ext':build_ext}, 
      ext_modules=[Extension("test",["test.pyx", "ctest.c"], 
                   extra_compile_args=['-g'],
                   extra_link_args=['-g', '-pthread'])
    ])
```

And running it:

```
$ python setup.py build_ext -i
running build_ext
cythoning test.pyx to test.c
# ...
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'
$ python
>>> import test
>>>
```

Tada.

Comment: The multiple definition is becasue the c file name is the same as the c file which will be generated by cython. So the solution is to change the c file name. Thank you very much.